# Is it possible to convert a string in to a programming statement in apex?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

```
Public String var='public String var1=\'Some text\'; ' ;
```

I require this string inside var to execute and create a variable "Var1" and assigned with the value "Some text".

Is it possible to do this? If Yes then how will it be possible?

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51707/how-to-create-object-by-its-name - I assume, u know how to parse the string and get value, which u want to assign. Other stuff should be in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sort of. It is possible to mimic a Javascript eval() in Apex by making a callout to the executeAnonymous API method.

There are two common ways you can get a response back from executeAnonymous.

1. Throw a deliberate exception at the end of the execute and include the response. Kevin covers this approach in [EVAL() in Apex. Secure Dynamic Code Evaluation on the Salesforce1 Platform](https://codefriar.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/eval-in-apex-secure-dynamic-code-evaluation-on-the-salesforce1-platform/).
2. I used a variation of this approach but returned the response via the debug log rather than an intentional exception. See [Adding Eval() support to Apex](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/11/adding-eval-support-to-apex.html).

Using my example the Apex would be something like:

```
public string var = soapSforceCom200608Apex.evalString(
                'String var1=\'Some text\'; System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, var1);');
```

You might not be able to perform the callout during member initialisation or in a constructor.

Incidentally, the [Salesforce Stackexchange site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/7792/102) is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.